# Consulta con sentencias preparadas no me arroja los valores

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

Estoy haciendo un simple login para hacer un simple ejercicio, tengo mis dos inputs de contraseña y usuario, el método que utilizo es `POST`, estoy creando mi sentencia preparada, no me arroja ningún error, simplemente no me imprime el valor que tengo en mis variables `$pass` y `$nombre` pero lo que tengo comentado que es como normalmente lo hago si me trae el resultado de mi BD, estoy utilizo **Windows** la versión de PHP es 7.3.1 y estoy utilizando **XAMPP**, leí que podía ser el mysqlnd, pero en las versiones de PHP 5.4 en adelante ya viene activado, no sé que este haciendo mal o que no tenga instalado, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano.

```
<?php  

    //var_dump($_POST);

    if (isset($_POST["enviar"])) {


    $con = new mysqli('?','?','','?') or die ('No se pudo conectar');

    /*$con = mysqli_connect('?','?','','?') or die ('No se pudo conectar');

    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];

    $query = "SELECT pass,nombre FROM datos WHERE nombre = '$usuario' AND pass = $password";

    $ejecutaQuery = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutaQuery)) {
        echo $fila[0];
    }*/

    $query = "SELECT pass,nombre FROM datos WHERE nombre = ? AND pass = ?";

    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];

    $sentencia = $con->prepare($query);
    $sentencia->bind_param('si',$usario, $password);
    $sentencia->execute();
    $sentencia->store_result();

    if ($sentencia->num_rows > 0) {
        $sentencia->bind_result($pass, $nombre);
        while ($sentencia->fetch()) {
            echo $pass.'-'.$nombre;
            }
    }else{

        echo "no funciona";

    }






    $sentencia->close();

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Yo cambiaría en tu pregunta el mencionar HeidiSQL pues esa solo es una herramienta para conectarte a tu gestor de bases de datos, que seguro o es MySQL o MariaDB

Comment: Ya la edite, gracias. :)

Comment: El campo pass es númerico?

Comment: Si, es INT, estoy haciendo la prueba en mi trabajo, y tengo un archivo que esta alojado en un servidor, en ese archivo hago el mismo código y si me trae resultados, pero lo hago en el localhost y no me manda los datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error era tan sencillo nada más que ya estaba cansado y no lo vi :S
en

```
bind_param('si',$usuario. $password); //Debería estar así no estoy escribiendo bien la variable, 
    //pero no sé porque no me arrojaba algún error para identificarlo.

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];

    $sentencia = $con->prepare($query);
    $sentencia->bind_param('si',$usario, $password);
    $sentencia->execute();
    $sentencia->store_result();
```